# Retrieve title from rows with a maximum count in other columns

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, count, window-functions

Given the following table `archived`:

```
CREATE TABLE archived (
   sid       serial -- row id
   showurl   text   -- can be: btg, tmwwt, gcaf, emda
   title     text
   reference text   -- title id number
);
```

Sample Input:

```
sid | showurl | title       | reference
----+---------+-------------+-----------
1   | btg     | 01-Preface  | 01
2   | btg     | 01-Preface  | 01
3   | emda    | 26-Friction | 26
4   | tmwwt   | 13-Helper   | 13
5   | btg     | 05-Finale   | 05
6   | gcaf    | 07-Help     | 07
```

[SQLfiddle to work with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48e94)

Desired Output:

1st selection:  `showurl: 'btg'`

2nd selection: `reference: '01'`

3rd and final selection: `title: '01-Preface'`

---

I am trying to determine from table `archived` which `showurl` has the greatest number of rows.

Then, for that 'showurl', I need to identify which `reference` has the greatest number of rows. Obviously, that 'reference' will be duplicated, but the 'sid' associated with each duplicated 'reference' will be unique.
Once that is determined, I wish to select/display its `title`.

---

My initial attempt (using php, postgresql 9.2: queried each `showurl`, then using max to identify the `showurl` with the greatest number of hits.):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM archived WHERE showurl = 'btg' order by sid ASC";
$query = "SELECT * FROM archived WHERE showurl = 'tmwwt' order by sid ASC";
$query = "SELECT * FROM archived WHERE showurl = 'gcaf' order by sid ASC";
$query = "SELECT * FROM archived WHERE showurl = 'emda' order by sid ASC";

$max = max($numrows1,$numrows2,$numrows3,$numrows4);
```

Using the sample data above, `$max` would be 3, but `showurl`, `title`, `reference`, and `sid` are unavailable for further processing.

---

I have tried using `pg_numrows()` but I cannot find a way to refer back either to 'title' or 'reference' for the max rows.

I gather some form of `UNION` would be in order, but have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Sample data (and wanted output) would help more.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I have added more info (sample data and desired output)

Comment: Please consider how I reformatted your question. Also add the query you tried, even if it's not working! And don't forget to mention your version of PostgreSQL. Finally, please clarify more closely what5 you want to retrieve. What if the rows with the maximum for `showurl` do not match the ones for `reference`. How is the result defined exactly? Are we dealing with *completely* duplicate rows, except for `sid`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact requirements, something along these lines should work:

#### Subqueries to determine most common attributes

```
SELECT DISTINCT title
FROM   archived
WHERE  showurl = (
   SELECT showurl
   FROM   archived
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY count(*) DESC, 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
AND    reference = (
   SELECT reference
   FROM   archived
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY count(*) DESC, 1
   LIMIT  1
   );
```

I added `DISTINCT` to the outer `SELECT` to fold duplicate titles. It's undefined what you need exactly.

#### Shorter with window functions

A more modern / sophisticated / elegant approach would be with two [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in the `ORDER BY` clause, allowing for a very terse query:

```
SELECT title
FROM   archived
ORDER  BY count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY showurl)   DESC
         ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY reference) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Not necessarily faster than the first solution, though.
Again, guessing what you might want exactly, I only retrieve a *single* winning title.

The trick here is to partition the rows by `showurl` and `reference`, run a count over each partition and order descending by that count. This way, you can determine a winner in a single query level.

This will *not* work, if there is no row with the most common `showurl` and the most common `reference` at the same time. Again, exact requirements would be needed ...

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48e94/1)

Comment: Thank-you for an excellent reply, Erwin! Works great - never thought of doing it that way - I have a lot to learn! Your second shorter reply does the job admirably, and yes, I wanted only a single winning vote. Andre